# High number of internal exceptions has been detected. This indicates a serious problem with the IDE

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola a todos actualmente tengo este problema con android studio me da este error y me muestra casi todos los imports en rojo ademas de no dejarme abrir setting por ejemplo

High number of internal exceptions has been detected. This indicates a serious problem with the IDE. Please consider clean reinstall of Android Studio. If the problem persists, please report a bug by following the link below.

Lo que ya intente:

abri el log idea y me da este error:
2020-11-07 16:27:40,967 [  66361]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv]
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv]

borre las carpetas:
C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio4.0\config\cache

actualize todo lo que me aparecia en el check for update
reinicie android studio, la pc y tambien intente re instalandolo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Te está dando un problema en la versión de Java que utiliza el plugin CSV, que es superior a la que estas utilizando en el proyecto. El log te lo indica en esta frase en concreto:

```
(class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Deshabilitando el plugin en SDK Manager o eliminando de la carpeta indicada debería haberse solucionado, sino, prueba a cambiar la versión de Java que estás utilizando en el proyecto.

Para ello, entra en `File > Project Structure...` y selecciona la utilizada por Android Studio `JDK Location -> Embedded JDK: C:/Program Files/...`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esto no resuelve el problema, abre la consola de comandos de windows y escribe `java -versión`. Si la versión que tienes instalada es inferior a Java 11 instala una versión Java 11 o superior y seleccionala en `Project Structure`

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por comentar! te comento la opcion de sdk manager asi como el setting de android studio no me deja abrirlo. Actualize java a la version 11 me quedo asi java

```
version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

la elegi en proyect structure pero me sigue dando el mismo error en el log idea

Tengo una duda con respecto a las carpetas que borre de plugin y de cache (la cual cache se volvio a crear sola y plugins no) yo borre esas carpetas dentro de
C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio4.0\cache y  C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio4.0\plugins
y  en el post que lei indicaba que estas carpetas estabas dentro de config\plugins y config\cache no se si eso influye o no. Gracias nuevamente

```
2020-11-07 19:51:44,323 [  95610]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Android Studio 4.1  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069 
2020-11-07 19:51:44,323 [  95610]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-11-07 19:51:44,323 [  95610]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2020-11-07 19:51:44,324 [  95611]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Plugin to blame: CSV Plugin version: 2.14.3 
2020-11-07 19:51:44,324 [  95611]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Last Action: ShowLog 
2020-11-07 19:51:44,279 [  95566]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv]
```